# How to get a .PFX file from only a .CER from rapid SSL

Tags: azure, ssl

I have ordered SSL from RapidSSL and have used it on my current hosting environment. Now I am changing hosting to Azure and they require a .PFX file.

What I have is an email from Rapid SSL with a

and got an email with a Web Server certificate in text formed like this:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

And I got a INTERMEDIATE CA that has the same format:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

I can find a lot of guides converting to .PFX but they ask for a key file (PEM) and such, and all I got is this email with text.

Can anyone point me to a guide or something? I don't really understand why this has to be so complicated. :(

Any help is much appreciated.

/Brian

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use openssl.

*openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt*

The key file is just a text file with your private key in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what private key are we talking about? I only have the above mentioned text. I have openssl installed and have tried different things with no luck.

Comment: you should have private key for your certificate. You can get it from your CA.

Comment: OK - but they haven't provided a key. I will try and ask them for one then - but it seems strange to me that they don't provide it as standard. I guess this will take me a couple of days of waiting afterall. Grrr.

Comment: I am just as confused as before unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I could get it using their support. They had an online service where I could get it.